# JSP MySQL results

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I have written this function to get a list of items from a MySQL DB into JSP:

```
public List getBookList() throws SQLException
   {
      List  BookList = new ArrayList();


      ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM book" );



      while ( results.next() ) {
         BookBean  view  = new BookBean();

        view.setID(results.getString( 1 ));
        view.setName(results.getString( 2 ));
        view.setDescription(results.getString( 3));
        view.setCatID(results.getString( 4));
        view.setUID(results.getString(5 ));
        view.setDateAdded(results.getString( 6 ));
        view.setPicThumb(results.getString( 7 ));
        view.setPicLarge(results.getString( 8 ));




         BookList.add(view);
      }

      return BookList;
   }
```

How can I invoke this method to render my result set on a .jsp page, and is there any better way to rewrite this method??

Comment: there is to less code to descripe you the possible solutions...
post at least the servlet and the regarding jsp.

Comment: first of all you must read a tutorial on how servlets and jsp works, then you can integrate your code. eg http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes the method is good to go. all you need is take this ArrayList object to your jsp trhough `request.setAttribute` or call this method from jsp scriplet `<% somewhere on the top of the page... %>` then use `jstl` to render you ArrayList.

Here is the example for `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>` rendered in jsp trhough jstl

[click here for example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseForEachtoLoopThroughArrayList.htm)

Googled it out and you'll found a lots of example.

Answer (score 1):

using MVC design pattern you can set the values to a `model`, then set the model object to request in your `controller`. Then use

something like this

```
request.setAttrbute("key to access the model",your model Object);
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("path_to_your_jsp_page");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

then read the value in your JSP using `EL` or `JSTL`
There are many ways, but among them above is one of the way!